# Are "pop philosophy" questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

E.g. there was a [recent question](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/79656/what-does-it-mean-to-be-yourself) here on what it means to "be yourself", which is a buzzword in many self-help books and in some popular-culture contexts (and slightly more seriously in some organizational culture/psychology [contexts](https://hbr.org/2013/10/be-yourself-but-carefully).)

Are such questions on-topic here as-is? What is the philosophy SE answer to a question like this? E.g. enumerate over (all) possible philosophical takes [on the matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticity_(philosophy))?

Answer (score 3):

I'd say questions like that would be okay if they are tightly scoped to one particular philsophical school: "What does it mean in existentialism to "be yourself"?" "What would Nietzsche say it meant to "be yourself"?"

If it's not scoped like that, then such a question is just an open-ended invitation to pontificate on whatever you want. Close that down immediately.

Comment: Agree. Philosophy of person/self and writings on authenticity are too vast a field to cover if asked about without a specific scope.